# How is Sovereign Glue affected by Dispel Magic or an Antimagic Field?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, magic-items

Do objects tacked together with an application of *[Sovereign Glue](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wondrousItems.htm#sovereignGlue)* come off each other if targeted with *[Dispel Magic](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/dispelMagic.htm)* or brought inside an *[Antimagic Field](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/antimagicField.htm)*?

If so, can they be made to stick together again when the effect ends?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Vague and unclear, on both counts, I’m afraid. You’ll have to ask the DM and/or make your own choice if you are the DM.

In detail, *dispel magic* and *antimagic field* both have the effect of temporarily suppressing magic. And there are arguments for and against that working, as well as arguments for and against the *sovereign glue*’s adhesion being restored after the suppression ends.

#### Suppression Works

The argument for suppression working is that *sovereign glue* doesn’t say anything explicitly about it not working, and *sovereign glue*’s ability to join two surfaces is clearly magical. When suppressed, that adhesion goes away, and the two can be separated.

Note that found or bought *sovereign glue* has caster level 20th, making it rather difficult to dispel.

#### Suppression Doesn’t Work

*Sovereign glue* says this:

> If the glue is allowed to set, then attempting to separate the two bonded objects has no effect, except when *universal solvent* is applied to the bond.

This line notes a single, solitary exception to the blanket statement that the two bonded objects cannot be separated, and that is *universal solvent*. Since neither *dispel magic* nor *antimagic field* is *universal solvent*, their effects cannot allow the two bonded objects to be separated.

Basically, this is a question of which statement has priority: that magic-suppression stops magical effects from working, or that *sovereign glue* can be bested only by *universal solvent*. It’s not clear to me that either statement is officially more-primary than the other.

#### Adhesion Resumes when Suppression Ends

If we assume that *sovereign glue* can be suppressed, we then have to determine what happens when it stops being suppressed.

The default behavior for magic items is to just resume their normal function. In the case of *sovereign glue*, bonding two objects.

Even if we allow that, there are still questions:

- does the *sovereign glue* have to set again?
- does the *sovereign glue* only work with the objects it originally bonded to, or can it be applied to some other objects while suppressed and then allowed to bond those?
- if the *sovereign glue* is not between two surfaces when suppression ends, does it just become useless, as if the objects-to-be-bonded were separated during setting? or does it now become eligible to bond to whatever is placed on it (allowing for set, if necessary)?

The rules do not have answers to these questions.

#### Adhesion Doesn’t Resume when Suppression Ends

This could arguably be the case simply because *sovereign glue* is very much a one-shot deal. Certainly avoids a lot of questions, but barring some explicit statement about it, it seems rather contrary to the norms of magic suppression.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65783/discussion-on-answer-by-kryan-how-is-sovereign-glue-affected-by-dispel-magic-or).

Answer (score 14):

There is a strong economic argument to be had against dispel magic and antimagic field working on Sovereign Glue.

So, from the points below:

1. The description:

   > If the glue is allowed to set, then attempting to separate the two bonded objects has no effect, except when universal solvent is applied to the bond.
2. The cost of sovereign glue: 2,400gp per use.
3. The cost of [hiring someone](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Spellcasting_and_Services) to cast antimagic field: 660gp (caster level 11 for a 6th level spell, times 60gp) - dispel magic would be even cheaper per casting (150gp per cast), disregarding the high chance of failure.
4. **Speculative:** Since it is a single-use (per ounce) item, **one could argue** that the glue's magic is gone once it completes its effect, just as a healing potion: the healing cannot be dispelled once the potion did its magic. So the "Strong transmutation" aura could be only for the unset glue.
5. The effects of the spell used to craft Sovereign Glue are not dispelled by an antimagic field. An object repaired by Make Whole does not break again when brought inside an antimagic field.

I doubt any self-respecting lv 20 caster would spend 1,200gp to make an item that can be removed by [almost] half that value.

So I think the best ruling is:

> Sovereign glue is magical only before it sets. Once set, the bonding effect is not magical, and can only be dissolved by Universal Solvent as the item description says.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65784/discussion-on-answer-by-mindwin-how-is-sovereign-glue-affected-by-dispel-magic-o).